# List with buttons

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my app i have a list with custom row,in each row i have a button and i want to set all of the buttons to the same listener. when i define a listener to the button (btn in code) my app get crash
this is how i set the list:

```
private void updateResultsInUi() {         
        lv = getListView();  
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setCacheColorHint(0x00000000);

        ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter(this,R.layout.item_row, Catalog.instance());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setClickable(true); 

        Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.cellbtn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
              int l = 0;
              l++;
          }
        });

    }
```

this is my row xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
 <LinearLayout  
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">

     <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:weightSum="1" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="1">

         <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
             android:layout_height="100dp" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content">

             <Button android:id="@+id/cellbtn" 
                 android:layout_width="76px" 
                 android:layout_height="37px" android:background="@drawable/hazmanacell" 
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/> 

         </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="0dp" 
                     android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                 <TextView android:textSize="14dp" android:layout_weight="0.50" 
                 android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                 android:id="@+id/toptext" android:text="stam1" 
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                 android:gravity="right" android:textColor="@color/black" /> 

                 <TextView android:textSize="12dp" android:layout_weight="0.50" 
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                     android:text="stam1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                     android:id="@+id/centertext" android:gravity="right" 
                     android:textColor="@color/black" /> 


         </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageViewTwitterPic" 
    android:src="@drawable/icon" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

## Edit

In this line :

```
Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.cellbtn);
```

btn is null,any idea why it's happen?

Comment: Please post the error from the logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in each row i have a button....In your adapter(ItemsAdapter)**

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

        Button btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.cellbtn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        });
    }
```

**in Your row.xml**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/cellbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: Further to this I would recommend watching [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA) video, specifically the section on list views and performance, he explains in detail how to properly manage any list view with a custom adapter.

Comment: when i done like you suggest , i error on this line : `btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { `

Answer (score 0):

Why 
Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.cellbtn);

you must use Your_Item_Layout.findViewById(R.id.cellbtn);